# Sabre API - Guyana Country Code & Airport Code not working

Tags: sabre

Good Evening,

I have been exploring the APIs and have found no support for flights to or from Guyana. I have tried using the instaflightsearch, flight fares, city pairs, lead price calendar, etc.

Everytime I try to enter the Guyana country code (GY) or the airport code of our main international airport (GEO), I get an error similar to:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.test.sabre.com/v2/shop/flights/fares?origin=GEO&destination=JFK&departuredate=2015-12-30&lengthofstay=3,4,5,6,7): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in APIHandler->get() (line 132 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7\sites\all\modules\custom\sabre\classes\APIHandler.php).
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.test.sabre.com/v1/lists/supported/shop/flights/origins-destinations?origincountry=GY): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in APIHandler->get() (line 132 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7\sites\all\modules\custom\sabre\classes\APIHandler.php).
```

Note that if I use other airport codes such as JFK, LAX, LAS, etc., the APIs return results.

I am unsure how to proceed. I'm sure there is something I'm missing. Please point me in the right direction.

Thank you very much

**Side Note:** I am willing to give a 100 bounty to anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Sandbox/Test environment for some APis, this is much more limited that real live PRODUCTION environment on the amount of Markets and CIty Pairs supported for search.

Read More here:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_basics/Point_of_sale

With Bargain Finder Max, you can test such from Dev Environment if needed.

Comment: Thank you @jmacagno, I'll test out production and see if it works. Will be sure to give the bounty if you are indeed correct :).